# Cannot Create New Users with Django

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

As the title states, I've been having a huge problem adding users to my Django server as of late. I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUqUdu0Sjyc) on setting up user registration with Django when I realized that there were no users being created when I checked the admin panel.

In my `forms.py` file:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

In my `views.py` file:

```
def createUser(request):
    form = RegisterForm(response.POST)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect("/home")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "main/signup.html", context)
```

Here is a [link](https://codeshare.io/29AJj1) to `signup.html` without all the Django functions.

In `signup.html`, I tried three things:

1. Replaced each `<input>` tags with its respective `{{form.formfield}}`
2. Placed `{{form}}` in the next line after the `<form>` tag
3. Removed all HTML, CSS, and JS from the signup page and unlinked it from the template page and made the signup page consist of only

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.username.label}}
    {{form.username}}

    {{form.email.label}}
    {{form.email}}

    {{form.password1.label}}
    {{form.password1}}

    {{form.password2.label}}
    {{form.password2}}

    <input type="submit" name="Create User">
</form>
```

In all three of these attempts to get a user creation form that works, I ended up not only being unable to create a new user, but also was unable to create the form I needed. In my third attempt, all I got was a submit button with no form. Any help on this matter of mine would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it hosted in heroku ?

Comment: Can you please try rendering like this. `return render(request, "main/signup.html", {'form': form})` . You might say how does it matter. But believe me try it out.

Comment: No, it isn't hosted using Heroku, Sangeeth. I'm hosting the site on my local device. And I just tried out your suggestion, Shivendra. It still doesn't work after changing that line of code.